# Multiple IPv4 sending HTTP requests

Tags: java, http, ipv4

I'm new to the networking side of java and I need some help.

My ifconfig on my ubuntu machine:
(I have 3 IPs I want to use)

```
ens18
          inet addr:1.123.123.123  Bcast:1.123.191.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

ens18:0
          inet addr:1.123.123.124  Bcast:1.123.191.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

ens18:1
          inet addr:1.123.123.125  Bcast:1.123.191.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

I want to be able to send HTTP request through each of them, example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");

Proxy p = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("1.123.123.123", 8080));
Proxy p2 = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("1.123.123.124", 8080));
Proxy p 3= new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("1.123.123.125", 8080));


HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(p);

int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

etc... loop through all IPv4 on machine

I have looked on the internet and can't find any code that will work for what I'm trying to do.

1) How do I find all IPv4 on my machine
2) Is that the correct code to send HTTP request through each IP?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
InetAddress[] allAddresses = InetAddress.getAllByName("localhost");
InetAddress[] ip4Addresses = Arrays.stream(allAddresses)
                                   .filter(address -> address.getHostAddress().indexOf("::") == -1)
                                   .toArray(InetAddress[]::new);
```

2. Yes, that's how you send requests through a proxy

Comment: I get the IPv4 from that, but I still don't get how to use that as a proxy.

`Proxy p = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.DIRECT, new InetSocketAddress("1.123.123.123", 80));



HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(p);
`
-- I found how to get the IPv4 now, but I dont know how to request with them

Comment: what do you mean by you don't know how to request with them, you are doing just that in your posted code?

Comment: it doesn't work. Output: `java proxy type direct is not compatible with address`

Comment: Oh. You must pass `Proxy.NO_PROXY` to that method if you are directly connect to the resource (meaning no proxy involved)

Comment: Or leave blank (don't pass anything to openConnection)

Comment: Do you have skype or something? I think it'd be easier there to explain. If I use Proxy.NO_PROXY it will use the default IP set (Eth0) or "1.123.123.123" in this case. I want to be able to use Eth0:1 aka "1.123.123.125". If I pass in No proxy or leave parameter empty, I can't accomplish that. Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend you reading this helpful guide. [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)